# Make std::set to use conversion operator when compare elements

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++14, stdset

Currently I use `std::map` to save key/value pairs:

```
#include <map>

using K = int;
struct P {}; // some useful payload

int main()
{
    std::map< K, P const > m;
    m.insert({1, {}});
    auto it = m.find(1);
    // access:
    it->first;
    it->second;
}
```

`int` here is just for example. `mapped_type` is always `const` in my use case.

To access payload `P const` I have to use not too informative name `second`. The same regarding `first`. I want to name it simply `payload` or somehow else.

To achieve this, I invent the following approach:

```
#include <set>

using K = int;
struct P {};

struct A
{
    K key;
    P payload;
    operator K const & () const { return key; }
};

struct less
{
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator () (K const & l, K const & r) const
    {
        return l < r;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set< A, less > s;
    s.insert({1, {}});
    auto it = s.find(1);
    // access:
    it->key;
    it->payload;
}
```

Here I make `std::set` to use conversion operator every time for the key type. It works. But is it prohibited approach? Is there *undefined behaviour*?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me. (But I'm not sure enough to post it as an answer)

Comment: A lot of C++ programmers stay far away from using conversion operators due to questions just like yours.  Too many times, conversion operators either cause compilation issues, or if not that, run time issues when the programmer discovers their conversion operation is being used without them being aware it's being used.  Debugging such programs turns into a painful situation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right. But I want to use above approach somewhere into the depth of my library. User code will be far from such error-prone approaches.

Comment: Using such code in "depths of libraries" is more of a reason to stay away from conversion operators.  If that conversion operator fires for reasons you're not aware of, that becomes a big issue, wouldn't you say so?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Before release of this code I'll check it with `clang` tools for every use of a custom conversion operator. It is as safe as possible. I do not forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, it looks technically valid.

But it also falls into the category of "making your code so unnecessarily complex that a programmer has to look twice or thrice at it before they comprehend what on earth you're doing, and can validate that you're doing it correctly, and for basically no tangible benefit" which is very ungood.

Indeed, the fact that you — the code's own author, no less! — felt the need to come here asking for a language lawyer to validate the code's correctness is a big red flag that this is likely *not* worthwhile.

If at any point you feel that `.first` and `.second` are insufficiently descriptive for your code, you can instead get around that locally with such magic as:

```
auto& key     = it->first;
auto& payload = it->second;
```

or even:

```
auto& payload = getPayload(it);
```

where `getPayload` is an appropriate function taking an iterator of your particular type.

These approaches have the benefit of being fairly obvious, and of not requiring convening a session of the C++ Supreme Court to check them over first.

Comment: For C++1z it also can be clearly expressed in terms of decomosition (structured bindings). `auto & [key, payload] = *it`. But still it is extra layer of indirection.

Comment: @Orient In what way is it an extra layer of indirection? You mean lexically, right?

Comment: Lexically? Maybe, if you sure references will be optimized out.

Comment: @Orient: These references will definitely be optimized out. You're writing semantics not machine code :) At worst, it would still not be an extra layer of indirection; just a pointer copy of sorts.